# Azure Static WebApp NuxtJS 3 not finding _nuxt folder

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, nuxtjs3, azure-static-web-app

I am setting up build pipelines in Azure DevOps, but cannot get the NuxtJS 3 app to run when deploying via a Release Pipeline.

When deploying it straight from the DevOps Build Pipeline, it works.  This isn't ideal for us.

A new Build Pipeline was set up to create a build artifact, which works.  Downloading the artifact and publishing it from `swa` works as expected too.

The issue is when I use a Release Pipeline in DevOps, which has a `Deploy Azure Static Web App (Preview)` task, it doesn't work.  In the developer tools' network tab I can see a lot of 404 errors, all trying to access the `_nuxt` folder.

The Release Pipeline's step in YAML (it's extracted to the `zip` directory in previous step):

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Publishing Website'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: zip
    app_location: .app/.output/public
    output_location: .app/.output/public
    api_location: .app/.output/server
    config_file_location: .app
    skip_app_build: true
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'mytoken'
    deployment_environment: Dev
    production_branch: development
```

.app/swa-cli.config.json:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "configurations": {
    ".app": {
      "appLocation": ".output/public",
      "apiLocation": ".output/server",
      "outputLocation": ".output/public",
      "apiLanguage": "node",
      "apiVersion": "18",
      "appName": "test123",
      "resourceGroup": "dev-resources"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding the empty `.nojekyll` file out of desperation, but that didn't make a difference either.

**EDIT**

Build Definition:

```yaml
trigger:
  - development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - group: dev-variable-group
  - name: buildVersion
    value: $(Date:yyyyMMdd).$(Rev:r)
  - name: artifactName
    value: 'ui-artifact'

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildVersion;]$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      displayName: 'Set Build Version Variable'

    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '18.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: npm install -g pnpm
      displayName: 'Install pnpm'

    - script: |
        pnpm i
        pnpm build
      displayName: 'npm install and build'

    # Package the app into a zip file
    - script: zip -r $(buildVersion).zip .app
      displayName: 'Package app into ZIP'

    # Publish the zip as an artifact of the build
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathtoPublish: '$(buildVersion).zip'
        artifactName: $(artifactName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by removing `Deployment Environment`, `Production Environment`, and then also setting the `Output location` to an empty string (although I am not sure this makes any difference)

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  displayName: 'Publishing Website'
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: zip
    app_location: .app/.output/public
    api_location: .app/.output/server
    config_file_location: .app
    skip_app_build: true
    skip_api_build: true
    is_static_export: false
    verbose: true
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'token'
```

Comment: Glad that you can figure out the issue, and thanks for sharing the solution. Maybe, you can accept yourself answer as the solution of this case. This could be helpful for other people who are looking for a solution of the similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Since the **`AzureStaticWebApp@0`** task is a preview rather than stable version currently, there could be some defects on it. It is still in development and improvement.
It is not recommended to use the preview version task in your production processes and environment.

For your case, you can try by referencing the documentation "[**Deploy Nuxt 3 sites with universal rendering on Azure Static Web Apps**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-nuxtjs)".

Comment: The AzureStaticWebApp@0, despite being in preview, works when it's used in the Build Pipeline, so I figured the chances of that being the issue shouldn't be great.

When setting up the Static Web App in Azure and choosing DevOps as the source, it sets up the AzureStaticWebApp@0 by itself.

I am still holding up hope that it can be resolved.

Comment: @Pieter, Can you provide the definitions of your build pipeline and release pipeline?

Comment: I added the Build Pipeline's YAML too.  If that's not what you meant then please let me know.  The Release Pipeline only extracts the files and then use the YAML in my question to publish it.  The files in /public/assets folder are on the server (logo etc.), but _nuxt isn't.